# Tallit on Shabbat which is 9 av

Tags: shabbat, tisha-bav, tallit-gadol

Should one wear tallit gadol during the shachris on Shabbat if it is the 9 av (as in 2022)? On other shabbatot the person does wear a tallit.

I know that in this case the observance takes place on the next day. But still, the Shabbat is 9 av.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One does not perform any outer acts of mourning during Shabbos, even if it's the ninth of Av (see Mishnah Berurah [552:23](https://www.sefaria.org/Shulchan_Arukh%2C_Orach_Chayim.552.10?lang=he&p2=Mishnah_Berurah.552.23&lang2=he) and [553:6](https://www.sefaria.org/Shulchan_Arukh%2C_Orach_Chayim.553.2?lang=he&p2=Mishnah_Berurah.553.6&lang2=he)). The custom is those who normally wear a Tallis at Shacharis to refrain from wearing one when the fast of the ninth of Av is observed, as an act of mourning (see [Tur Orach Chaim 555](https://www.sefaria.org/Tur%2C_Orach_Chaim.555.1?lang=he)).

Consequently, if one usually wears a Tallis at Shacharis, they should continue to do when the ninth of Av occurs on Shabbos. Refraining would be forbidden, as that would be an outward act of mourning. Instead, the practices of the ninth of Av are delayed until the next day, including this custom regarding a Tallis.

Comment: Just to understand what you meant. When you write "it would be forbidden to do this" you mean "it would be forbidden to not to wear the tallit because it would be an act of mourning", right?

Comment: The answer is written in the double negative ("forbidden to refrain") which could be simplified, and the point that the answer has about "when the fast of the ninth of Av is observed" should be clarified to explain that when Shabbat is the ninth, the observance is on the 10th.

Comment: @rosends the point is it's *forbidden* to refrain, not that one *must* wear. The MB I cite says the same thing about meat. It's *forbidden* to refrain.

Comment: @robev but the question asks "should one" and the answer as presented is "one should not not". I would think that the answer, more simply would be "if one has the practice of wearing it, one should follow that practice"

Comment: @rosends better?

Answer (score 0):

There is a Yekkish Minhag that if one has a separate weekday tallis from their Shabbos tallis, he should wear his weekday tallis if Shabbos falls on the 9th of Av. However, he shouldn't talk about the fact that he is doing this on that Shabbos.
The same is done during the Shabbos of Shiva.

Comment: What about shabbat chazon which does not fall on 9 Av?

Comment: I believe the Maharil states to wear your weekday tallis on Shabbos Chazon if it wouldn't stand out, but I'm not sure if this is typically followed in actual practice.

Comment: The old Ashkenazi minhag is to wear weekday clothes entirely on every shabbat chazon